# How do I save a screenshot and load it as a texture for use in game?

Tags: c#, unity

I have a Unity level that takes a screenshot taken in the previous level and applies it as a material to a Plane, the problem is that it will get stuck and not apply the most recent version of the screenshot.

I figure that the best way would be to handle it with a C# script instead of just simply dragging and dropping the image file from the assets folder like I have been doing.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do in your game, you could store the screenshot to disk and later [load it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820890/loading-a-png-as-a-texture-at-runtime-in-unity3d) or you could hold the reference to the Texture2D in a [persistent object](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/576969/create-a-persistent-gameobject-using-singleton.html) (not advised if you want to keep many screenshots).

Either way, to load it assign it to a plane, simply do:

```
target.renderer.material.mainTexture = image;
```

Where `target` is the reference to the GameObject where the texture will be applied and `image` is the Texture2D.

Now, from what I understand you are capturing already the screenshots; but, what I do (as a Unity Free developer) is to capture and save it to disk, like this:

```
private IEnumerator TakeScreenshot()
{
    Camera cam = Camera.main;
    Texture2D image = new Texture2D(photoWidth, photoHeight); 

    RenderTexture currentRT = RenderTexture.active;

    RenderTexture.active = cam.targetTexture;
    cam.Render();

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    photoRect = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
    image.ReadPixels(photoRect, 0, 0);

    //Resize the image. Useful if you don't need a 1:1 screenshot.
    //4 is just used as an example. You could use 10 to resize it
    //to a tenth of the original scale or whatever floats your boat.
    if (resizePhotos)
        TextureScale.Bilinear(image, image.width / 4, image.height / 4);

    image.Apply();
    RenderTexture.active = currentRT;

    target.renderer.material.mainTexture = image;

    //Save it as PNG, but it could easily be changed to JPG
    byte[] bytes = screenshot.EncodeToPNG();

    string filename = "MyScreenshot";

    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
    Debug.Log(string.Format("Took screenshot to: {0}", filename));
}
```